# Category Filter Overlapping Content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a category filter set up on a Table Chart. The category list is derived from a list in sheets. Multiple categories have lengthy names. When the drop down on the category filter is chosen it renders the selections outside of the panel border and overlaps with the content behind it. Is there anything that I can do in Apps Script to clean this up?

[image: screenshot]

This is the data in 'Sheet1', in csv format (for easy import):

```
column1,column2,heading
data,   data,   category0
data,   data,   category1
data,   data,   category2
data,   data,   category3
data,   data,   the category that had a lengthy name and is overlapping content
data1,  data1,  category0
data1,  data1,  category1
data1,  data1,  category2
data1,  data1,  category3
data1,  data1,  the category that had a lengthy name and is overlapping content
data2,  data2,  category0
data2,  data2,  category1
data2,  data2,  category2
data2,  data2,  category3
data2,  data2,  the category that had a lengthy name and is overlapping content
data3,  data3,  category0
data3,  data3,  category1
data3,  data3,  category2
data3,  data3,  category3
data3,  data3,  the category that had a lengthy name and is overlapping content
```

Code:

```
  function doGet() {
    var templateDocId = "1UH....";
    var ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateDocId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var data0 = ss0.getDataRange();

    var quarterfilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();

    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1,2])).setDimensions(700,300).build()

    var dashboard0 = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data0).bind([quarterfilter],[tableChart]).build();

    var app0 = UiApp.createApplication()
    var filterpanel = app0.createVerticalPanel().add(app0.createHorizontalPanel().add(app0.createLabel("List").setStyleAttribute("fontSize","20")))
    var chartpanel = app0.createHorizontalPanel().add(app0.createVerticalPanel().add(tableChart))

    filterpanel.add(quarterfilter);
    chartpanel.setSpacing(20);
    dashboard0.add(app0.createVerticalPanel().add(filterpanel).add(chartpanel));
    app0.add(dashboard0);
    return app0;

  }
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I posted the code. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours and hours on this over the past week, and I can find no way to adjust the size of the selection box or to enforce items within it to conform to the widget width.

You have the ability to control the layout of *selected* categories, using `.setLabelStacking(orientation)`, but there is no similar method to control how those categories will be displayed in the selector.

There has been no report of this filed on the [Google Apps Script Issues Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=component=ChartsService&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner). You should report the issue. If you add a link to the issue back here, then others who share this pain will be encouraged to go and vote for it.

#### Work-arounds

The selector automatically adjusts its width, to a limit that can accommodate about 30 characters. Therefore, one less-than-ideal option would be to truncate your category names in the spreadsheet. This would give you the best control over what was displayed.

An alternate that would leave your spreadsheet untouched would be to pull your data from the spreadsheet and truncate the wider column as you build the `dataTable` yourself. This would give you something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

#### Code

Since a `dataTable` cannot be modified once it's built (or generated from a Range), we will need to make our own. To simplify that, this function makes the same assumptions that would be made with a Range. It accepts a two-dimensional array of values, and returns a `dataTable` we can use with Charts. ([Available as a gist.](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/8714493))

```
/**
 * Produce a dataTable object suitable for use with Charts, from
 * an array of rows (such as you'd get from Range.getValues()).
 * Assumes labels are in row 0, and the data types in row 1 are
 * representative for the table.
 *
 * @param {Array} data  Array of table rows
 *
 @ @returns {DataTable} Refer to GAS documentation
 */
function dataTableFromArray( data ) {
 var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
  for (var col=0; col<data[0].length; col++) {
    var label = data[0][col];
    var firstCell = data[1][col];
    if (typeof firstCell == 'string')
      dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, label);
    else
      dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, label);
  }
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    dataTable.addRow(data[row]);
  }  
  return dataTable.build();
}
```

This next function takes care of truncating data that we want to use as categories in a picker. Rather than blindly operate on all columns, it accepts an optional array of column numbers (starting from 0) that will have the maximum length enforced.

```
/**
 * Ensure the text in the indicated columns does not exceed the
 * given maximum length. The data table is changed in place, but
 * is also returned for chaining.
 *
 * @param {Array}    data    Array of Rows
 * @param {Number}   maxLen  Maximum string length to enforce
 * @param {Array}    columns (optional) Array of column numbers
 *                           for enforcement
 *
 * @returns {Array}  Resulting array for chaining.
 */
function truncateLongText( data, maxLen, columns ) {
  if (maxLen < 10) throw new Error( 'maxLen too small' );  // Truncating becomes pointless
  var elipses = '...';
  var frontLen = Math.ceil(2*maxLen / 3);
  var backlen = (maxLen-frontLen-elipses.length);
  for (var row=0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col=0; col<data[row].length; col++) {
      if (columns != undefined && columns.indexOf(col) != -1) {
        var cell = data[row][col];
        if (typeof cell == 'string' && cell.length > maxLen) {
          var front = cell.slice(0,frontLen);
          var back = backlen > 0 ? cell.slice(-backlen) : '';
          cell = front + elipses + back;  // Truncate cell contents
          data[row][col] = cell;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

And here's your example chart using these functions to produce the screenshot shown above. Note that `data0` is no longer a `dataTable`, it's now an `array`:

```
function doGet() {
    var templateDocId = "1UH....";
    var ss0 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateDocId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var data0 = truncateLongText(ss0.getDataRange().getValues(),30,[2]);

    var quarterfilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();

    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1,2])).setDimensions(700,300).build()

    var dashboard0 = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTableFromArray(data0)).bind([quarterfilter],[tableChart]).build();

    var app0 = UiApp.createApplication()
    var filterpanel = app0.createVerticalPanel().add(app0.createHorizontalPanel().add(app0.createLabel("List").setStyleAttribute("fontSize","20")))
    var chartpanel = app0.createHorizontalPanel().add(app0.createVerticalPanel().add(tableChart))

    filterpanel.add(quarterfilter);
    chartpanel.setSpacing(20);
    dashboard0.add(app0.createVerticalPanel().add(filterpanel).add(chartpanel));
    app0.add(dashboard0);
    return app0;

  }
```